# Separating multiple values within one cell into multiple cells

Tags: r, excel, function

I am working with patent data and I have multiple values (International Patent Classifications) separated by a comma in one cell. For instance: C12N, C12P, A01 (within one cell). I would like to analyze how many different 4-digit classifications each patent has. To do so, I need to, first, separate the individual values and put each of them into an individual cell. Second, I need to count the unique values (each placed then in separate columns) for each row.

How can I separate the individual values within one cell into multiple cells within Excel or R. Is there any excel or R function you can suggest?

Here is reproducible example on how the data looks like in R or in Excel.

```
#Example of how the data looks like 
Publication_number<-c(12345,10012,23323,44556,77999)
IPC_class_4_digits<-c("C12N,CF01,C345","C12P,F12N,F039","A014562,F23N", "A01C, A01B, A01F, A01K, A01G", "C10N, C10R, C10Q, C12F")

data_example<-cbind(Publication_number, IPC_class_4_digits)
View(data_example)
```

The expected about should be a column "counts" counting the number of different 4-digit numbers. In this case => c(3, 3, 2, 5, 4)

Comment: If one cell (here `A1` ) does only feature unique values, then you can count the number of comma-separated entries with `=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A,",",""))+1`

Comment: `@Qualia`: thanks a lot! Not 100% sure what the LEN function does. It counts the number of string characters I think so? I have tried and it does not work. So, does this also work if the number of comma separated values (e.g. C12N, C12P, A01) differs within the column? Kindly see the above written R example. I have for instance 2 cells having three different string values ("C12N,CF01,C345","C12P,F12N,F039")  and the third only has 2 ("A014562,F23N").

What I want in the end is an extra column that counts the number of different string values: e.g. c(3,3,2) for the example above.

Comment: There was on mistake in the above formula: `=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1`. `LEN` counts the length of the cell content. What I am doing, is counting the number of commas and add 1.

Comment: @Qualia: thanks and make sense, yes! I have tried, but unfortunately it doesn't work. I have uploaded an example as well on excel on Github: https://github.com/zepmaya/Example_MultipleValues_1Cell/blob/main/Example_Seperating_Values.xlsx

I am not sure if the LEN function works dynamically when having different amount of string values for each row?

Comment: @RonakShah: my expected output would be a column having the counts of the number for every 4-digits codes per row. Following the R example above this would be In this case => c(3, 3, 2, 5, 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string on comma and count it's length.

```
data_example$count <- lengths(strsplit(data_example$IPC_class_4_digits, ','))
data_example

#  Publication_number           IPC_class_4_digits count
#1              12345               C12N,CF01,C345     3
#2              10012               C12P,F12N,F039     3
#3              23323                 A014562,F23N     2
#4              44556 A01C, A01B, A01F, A01K, A01G     5
#5              77999       C10N, C10R, C10Q, C12F     4
```

Or another option is to use `str_count` -

```
data_example$count <- stringr::str_count(data_example$IPC_class_4_digits, ',') + 1
```

**data**

```
data_example<-data.frame(Publication_number, IPC_class_4_digits)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a dataframe with two columns `Publication_number` and `IPC_class_4_digits` you could use `cSplit` from `splitstackshape` package:

```
library(splitstackshape) 

# assuming your data
df <- data.frame(Publication_number, IPC_class_4_digits)
 
cSplit(df, 'IPC_class_4_digits', ',')
```

Output:

```
   Publication_number IPC_class_4_digits_1 IPC_class_4_digits_2 IPC_class_4_digits_3
1:              12345                 C12N                 CF01                 C345
2:               1001                 C12P                 F12N                 F039
3:               2332              A014562                 F23N                 <NA>
```

Comment: thanks, somehow I get the following error here:

 1: In type.convert.default(X[[i]], ...) :
  'as.is' should be specified by the caller; using TRUE
2: In type.convert.default(X[[i]], ...) :
  'as.is' should be specified by the caller; using TRUE
3: In type.convert.default(X[[i]], ...) :
  'as.is' should be specified by the caller; using TRUE

Comment: Try: `df %>% as_tibble() %>% type.convert(as.is = TRUE)`